# jQuery: stop animation from element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, unbind

when applying animation to an element - eg. div.animate() - how can i unbind that animation from single elements?

i've tried div.unbind() and div.unbind("animate") but didnt work..

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
$('#div').stop(); // this stop the currently-running animation
```

The animation is not bind to an element, it is just an effect => you can't unbind

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to stop the animation on the selected element instead of completely switching animations for all elements, simply use div.stop() or div.clearQueue()

http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

if you actually use div.stop(true), it will actually call clearQueue as well.

Answer (score 2):

for a single element:

```
$(selector).clearQueue().stop();
```