# jQuery - destroy animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, destroy

How to destroy created animation on same element?

For example:
I have animation

```
$('#sortable').animate({
    paddingTop: 85
}, 100);
```

And on same action I want to destroy it, because I done need it anymore.
Something like:

```
$('#sortable').animate('destroy');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by destroy ? stop ?

Comment: try this? jQuery.fx.off = true;

Comment: I think the answer is already on StackOverflow

See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077933/jquery-stop-animation-from-element
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378405/jquery-bind-unbind-animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#sortable').stop(true);// first argument removes all animations in the queue
```